# is there a way to import/export a pipes source in text/xml format?

Tags: pipe, yahoo-pipes

I'd like to save a copy of some of my pipes offline before I go to edit them, and possibly reload them from an external source again in future.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Open a Firebug console in the pipe edit page and type `dump()`

It will open another window with a JSON dump of the pipe.

It's up to you to interpret this or reload the pipe from this JSON :-)

Comment: don't know... use firebug to find out, that's how I found out about dump()... then post it here!

Comment: ok so I got the json and in firefox it renders the json but not quite the way expected - form elements of each module also seem to be rendered.

I'll accept this as the answer anyway seeing as it was a pretty inventive way of almost hacking out the one I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

If somebody just need to export, you can also make an HTTP request like so:

`http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id={THE_PIPE_ID}&_out=json&format=json`